# React admin: how to show some data in create component, from the page where create button was clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

React admin: how to show some data in create from page where create button was clicked.

I have a client create compoenent:

```
export const ClientCreate = (props) => (
    <Create {...props}>
      <SimpleForm>
        <ReferenceInput label="Realm" source="realm_id" reference="realms">
          <SelectInput optionText="id"/>
        </ReferenceInput>
<TextInput fullWidth="true" source="client_name" label="Client name"/>
```

Here this create component shows list of relms to select, but i want to show a single relm for which this client creation is triggered.

How can i pass relm_id from the view where we are triggering the create view

```
<TopToolbar>
      <CreateButton basePath="/clients"/>
</TopToolbar>
```

And this is my App looks likeconst App = () => (

```
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} layout={AppLayout}>
        <Resource name="realms" list={RealmsList} show={RealmShow} edit={RealmEdit} create={RealmCreate}/>
        <Resource name="clients" edit={ClientEdit} create={ClientCreate}/>
    </Admin>
);:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the original CreateButton, but you can create your component based on
[createButton](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/button/CreateButton.tsx) and pass data through the "state" property of the Link component:

```
MyCreateButton.tsx:
...
<StyledFab
    component={Link}
    to={createPath({ resource, type: 'create' })}
    state={scrollStates[String(scrollToTop)]} // {scrollStates[String(scrollToTop)], realm_id: 'realm value'}
...
<Button
    component={Link}
    to={createPath({ resource, type: 'create' })}
    state={scrollStates[String(scrollToTop)]} // {scrollStates[String(scrollToTop)], realm_id: 'realm value'}


Clients.tsx:
...
export const ClientCreate = (props) => {                    
  const locate = useLocation()
  const cardId = locate.state?.realm_id

  console.log('ClientCreate, location:', locate) 
->
ClientCreate, location: 
{
  pathname: '/clients/create',
  search: '',
  hash: '',
  state: {
    _scrollToTop: true, 
    relm_id: 'realm value'  
  },
  key: 's8x48fn3'
}
```

Another option is to pass the data through the URL by adding it to the "to" property:

```
to={createPath({ resource, type: 'create' }) + '?realm_id=' + encodeURIComponent('realm value')} 

...
const locate = useLocation()
const params = new URLSearchParams(locate.search)
console.log('ClientCreate, realm_id:', params.get('realm_id'))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the url approach please?

Comment: got an example of "to" property here: https://marmelab.com/blog/2020/09/16/react-admin-tutorials-form-for-related-records.html

Comment: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/AdvancedTutorials.html#creating-a-record-related-to-the-current-one